# Python3 Global Variable Issue

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, global-variables

I am trying to learn about loops and conditions. Therefore I coded a generator, which randomly create lotto/lottery numbers. However I created a global variable 'valCount', which stores the generation count. But still got this error:

> Bitte die Anzahl zu erzeugender Lottoscheine angeben: 2
> Input is an integer number. Number =  2
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Volumes/HDD/Users/Stephan/PycharmProjects/LottZahlenGeneratorLoop/main.py", line 87, in 
> check_user_input(userCountInput)
> File "/Volumes/HDD/Users/Stephan/PycharmProjects/LottZahlenGeneratorLoop/main.py", line 70, in check_user_input
> outPutCount()
> File "/Volumes/HDD/Users/Stephan/PycharmProjects/LottZahlenGeneratorLoop/main.py", line 55, in outPutCount
> for x in range(valCount):
> NameError: name 'valCount' is not defined

Correct behaviour:
User needs to input a number. This number get validated, if it is a digit or a letter. If this is a digit, the lotto/lottery numbers should be created by the count of users input. Otherwise, user is asked to enter number.

My code:

```python3
# IMPORTS
import random
from datetime import datetime
import os


# CLEAR CONSOLE
def clearConsole():
    command = 'clear'
    if os.name in ('nt', 'dos'):  # If Machine is running on Windows, use cls
        command = 'cls'
    os.system(command)


# VARIABLES
date = datetime.now()
dateFormat = str(date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))

mainNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
               29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
superNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
mainNumbersLotto = mainNumbers
del mainNumbersLotto[49]  # löscht die 49. Stelle von mainnumbers, da Lotto 6aus49 nur Zahlen von 1-49 existieren
global valCount

# countToCreate = input("Bitte geben sie die Anzahl zum generieren an.")

# FUNCTION EUROJACKPOT GENERATOR
def eurojackpotFunc():
    global eurojackpotOutput
    RandomMainNumbers = str(sorted(random.sample(mainNumbers, 5)))
    RandomSuperNumbers = str(sorted(random.sample(superNumbers, 2)))
    eurojackpotOutput = "\nEurojackpot\n5 aus 50: " + RandomMainNumbers + "\nEurozahlen: " + RandomSuperNumbers
    print(eurojackpotOutput)


# FUNCTION Lotto6aus49 GENERATOR
def lottoNumbersFunc():
    global lottoNumbersOutput
    RandomLottoNumber = str(sorted(random.sample(mainNumbersLotto, 6)))
    lottoNumbersOutput = "\nLotto6aus49\n6 aus 49: " + RandomLottoNumber
    print(lottoNumbersOutput)


# FUNCTION GENERATE TEXTFILE WITH RESULT
def generateTxtFile():
    f = open("Lottozahle" + "- " + dateFormat + ".txt", "+w")
    f.write(eurojackpotOutput + "\n " + lottoNumbersOutput)

def check_user_input(input):
    try:
        # Convert it into integer
        valCount = int(input)
        print("Input is an integer number. Number = ", valCount)
        outPutCount()

    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Convert it into float
            valCount = float(input)
            print("Input is a float  number. Number = ", valCount)
            userCountInputFunc()
        except ValueError:
            print("No.. input is not a number. It's a string")
            userCountInputFunc()

def userCountInputFunc():
    global userCountInput
    userCountInput = input("Bitte die Anzahl zu erzeugender Lottoscheine angeben: ")

#
def outPutCount():
    # LOOP FOR GENERATING COUNT
    global valCount
    xCount = 0
    for x in range(valCount):
        xCount = xCount + 1
        print("\n#################")
        print(xCount, ". Generation")
        eurojackpotFunc()
        lottoNumbersFunc()
        generateTxtFile()
        valCount = str(valCount)
        print("\nEs wurden erfolgreich " + valCount + " Lottoscheine generiert.")

userCountInputFunc()
check_user_input(userCountInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows `NameError: name 'valCount' is not defined` (within your loop), and from the looks of it, you're attempting to define it twice– within `outPutCount` and in the true global scope. As an aside, no matter where you use the keyword `global`, it will always belong to the global scope.

Anyways, this is the problem with global variables (especially ones that have no value assigned to them before run-time)– figuring out their value while letting various areas in the code mutate them is a self-induced headache worth avoiding.

Try passing the value you want into the function by way of its arguments. You can implement this entire program without the usage of a global variable.

Hope that helps, and keep learning!

Comment: Thank you for your review. But how does it work without global variable? Maybe add all functions into one?

Comment: Sure thing @StephanKoenig . Like I mentioned, pass variables into your functions as arguments. In your case, your error stems from mutating a global variable `valCount`, which has no value (`undefined`) and then you attempt to give it a value `int(input)`, but then in the scope of `outPutCount` you again declare `global valCount` again without any value (`undefined`). Passing arguments as functions is a better practice